# How to use MongoDB in TypeScript with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

Following this tutorial, but they do not use Typescript as me, and got stuck: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIlYroSsInU&t=248s

Got this error

> Property 'mongoClient' does not exist on type '{ mongoClient: any; } | undefined'.

```js
// /pages/api/list.ts

import { connectToDatabase } from '../../lib/connectToDatabase'
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
) {
    try {
        const { mongoClient } = await connectToDatabase() // <--- HERE
        const db = mongoClient.db('sample_restaurants')
        const collection = db.collection('restaurants')
        const results = await collection.find({}).project().toArray()
        res.status(200).json({ results })
    } catch (e) {}
}
```

and

```js
// connectToDatabase.ts

import { MongoClient, MongoClientEvents, TypedEventEmitter } from 'mongodb'
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI as string
const options = {}
let mongoClient: TypedEventEmitter<MongoClientEvents>

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
    throw new Error('Error')
}

export async function connectToDatabase() {
    try {
        if (mongoClient) {
            return { mongoClient }
        }
        mongoClient = await new MongoClient(uri, options).connect()
        return { mongoClient }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share any more of your code? It seems like the possibility of the return type being undefined is the issue.

Comment: ahh yes, did so

Comment: In `api/list.ts` you need to check if `mongoClient` is defined before using it. Typescript is correctly warning you that there's no guarantee the function returns a value, and you don't check for that case, so your code could fail if your fn errors. Or you could throw / remove the catch in `connectToDatabase` so that errors will prevent the rest of the code from executing

Comment: Warning is raised when unwrapping, not when accessing `mongoClient`. Here: `const { mongoClient } = await connectToDatabase()`

Comment: Also in catch block you're not returning anything so make sure you handle that as well. :D

Comment: Illustration of AndyRay's comment: https://tsplay.dev/m362AN